# ASP.NET vs DotNetNuke (DNN) for Enterprise-class Application

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I am in the process of architecting an application. It will be a large, enterprise class web application. Thousands of users could upload files, search large number of blog entries with chat functionality and such. It will also have mobile interface. It should be highly testable, scalable and flexible.

I have narrowed it down to three environments: pure play ASP.NET, pure play DotNetNuke (DNN) and a combination of ASP.NET and DNN. To keep this very brief, here are some 'for' and 'against' on each of the options:

ASP.NET:
for: highly scalable, supports patterns like MVC, testable, consistent architecture.
against: long development time.

DotNetNuke:
for: short development time, large number of existing functional modules and skins.
against: architecture is sealed, can't support MVC, unit testing is difficult, inconsistent modules/skins, potential upgrade issues, user experience is inconsistent due to disparate modules from different vendors, poor documentation.

So, the questions are: what do you think? Has anyone switched from DNN to ASP.NET (and, vice versa)? Have you objectively evaluated these two and what did you choose?

Highly appreciate your help. Thanks.
henry.

Comment: Your comparison isn't really valid. ASP.NET is a platform. DNN is a Content Management System built on ASP.NET. You're really asking if you should use a Content Management System for your site or not.

Comment: Agreed; but, DNN does allow building a serious application with wide ranging functionality. It may have started off as CMS (still is); but, its functionality has gone far beyond the initial intend. Thanks.

Comment: to be honest it depends on the time you have to develop.  DNN has alot already done and ready to use modules which of course you can add but it's easier to just add a module then create a whole CMS and System..I've used it and recommend it but there are situations where i've had to do from scratch everything..so been on boths sides bout this and recommend either one.

Comment: How big is your development team?  When is your go live date?

Comment: To Andres, Brent: I am assessing these options for a client (I am a consultant). I don't have precise details; but, the dev team size is small (probably about 5). The team size could go up. Not sure about the project schedule. Though the current application is based on CMS, future plans require consistent user experience, scalability, simplicity and reliability. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

DNN is ASP.NET, just with a lot of the work done for you.

Also, please remember that just because raw ASP.NET has the potential to be more scalable, doesn't mean that you are actually going to built it to be more scalable.  Or that you will built it well in the first place.

It comes down to a trade off between control and resouces/talent.  If you have many very talented developers (like, top-10% talent), a lot of time, clearly defined requirements for your site, and consumers who will be patient while you build out the infrastruture, by all means go with raw ASP.NET.

However, if you need to build it quickly and need to be flexible, or you have limited development resources, you might have to sacrifice some of that control and unit testing and potential performance (again, the "potential" part is key here).

Based on what you are looking for, I'd recommend you go with a platform like DNN, or a million other ones line SiteFinity or Umbraco or Orchard or something like that (some of them like Umbraco give you MVC too).  It gives you a lot of the infrastructure and plumbing common among a lot of sites, probably done better than you are going to do it, so that you can focus your resources on the truly unique aspects of  your application.

Just stay away from SharePoint.  It's evil.

I've built raw ASP.NET sites for really customized applications, which was good because I didn't need a lot of plumbing and wanted really unique funcitonality through the site.  But then I've built social networking sites with DNN, which worked well because it had packaged components for blogs and forums and chat and all that stuff, plus allowed for easy skinning.  I designed another application for a customer that they wanted to have a lot of custom functionality, but they also wanted to updated a lot of content and internatalized it, so we used a Umbraco for that.  And right now I have a ASP.NET app that works great, but I want to add in some social features, so I'm going plug in a Umbraco or DNN site that integrates with it to host the more common social components.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I agree that a lot depends on how well you execute in building an ASP.NET app and replicating the functionality that are readily available in DNN. That's a reason why I have the hybrid model as an option (as you are with ASP.NET and Umbraco/DNN). Have you faced problems with making all those disparate modules to work together and create a consistent user experience? What about upgrade issues with the modules? Thanks. (funny thing about SharePoint! have a few questions on that for later!)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend DNN based on your very limited list of needed features. You can always build a custom module to meet your exact needs or modify an existing open source module as needed. You can use the MVP approach in your module development to improve the testability.

Comment: Thanks. In my assessment, I am keeping the DNN as the continued option, while evaluating Umbraco.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered the Umbraco CMS? It is built on .Net (v5 is MVC3). It is open source and a very robust and well supported application. It has been used for the asp.net site for example.

It has a very short development time, many modules, extremely flexible and I find it very easy to extend. For example, I rolled my own workflow, event driven publishing and have created multiple custom administration sections for managing bespoke functionality external to Umbraco.

You can use XSLT, Usercontrols or Razor to create template modules.

It has a fantastic community too.

Comment: No, I haven't looked at Umbraco yet (though it was on my list of competing platforms). My client (I am a consultant) already has this app in DNN. We are assessing various options for future growth. I am going to look into seriously. Thanks.